# Python Flask Immediate Response

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I have an application in python which takes long time to compute .I need to create REST end Point to it .I created it using Flask .But i need the sever to respond immediately that the request has been accepted .How can Do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't want the result of your heavy computing inside the response body of the request. You can still spawn a thread inside the view and return the http code 202/Accepted which indicates that "the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed."[RFC-2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Which should give the following code

```
import httplib
from threading import Thread

from flask import Flask, Response

from mymodule import heavy_lift

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/async")
def async_start():
    Thread(target=heavy_lift).start()
    return Response(status=httplib.ACCEPTED)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If you want to perform heavy async stuff with Flask, I suggest using a distributed task queue such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) which is quite Flask friendly (cf [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/))

Comment: Persist the result somewhere such as a db. When the user makes a request to /async send him back a 202 and in the body give him an id that he can use afterward to poll another endpoint to get the status/result of the job (e.g. /job/<string:uuid>/status).

Comment: got it .is there ny to do it without involving the db